# How to combine database and if this is the best method for database design

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I am creating a database very similar to skip the dishes and each item on the menu add ons(ex:add salad). I want to join them together where the food is with their side dishes.If you guys can please visually show me because it's hard to imagine especially when I'm still new to this thank you.
So the main point I am asking is

- Is this efficient for a database design?
- What would be the best way to combine the 2 tables together?

---

```
Table1(Food)           

co1(food_name)   col2(price)
Salmon           9.95
Beef with rice   11.50
Turkey           13.95
Chicken          9.95
```

---

```
Table2(Add-on)

col1(addon_name)           col2(food_name)    col3(price)
side salad                 salmon             2.50
side rice                  salmon             2.50
side potatoes              salmon             2.50
gravy                      beef with rice     1.50
side potatoes              beef with rice     2.50
side rice                  Turkey             2.50
gravy                      Turkey             1.50
gravy                      Chicken            1.50
```

Ex of wanted result

```
salmon|9.95|side salad|2.50|side rice|2.50|side potatoes|2.50
Turkey|9.95|side rice|2.50|gravy|1.50
Chicken|9.95|gravy|1.50
```

Comment: should have a third table with food to add-on using ids, rather than duplicates in the Add-on table

Comment: If the add-on is the same price no matter what the food is, you should normalize your `add-on` table.

Comment: Read up on [Data Normalization](http://agiledata.org/essays/dataNormalization.html).

Comment: Hi. Please read hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & show what you tried. Please read & act on [mcve]. It is not clear what exact output you want so write some code that sets a table to that value. PS Time to read a textbook on information modeling, the relational model & database design. (Nb--A manual for a design tool, api or language to record designs is not a manual/tutorial on design.)

Comment: @Barmar lets say hypothetically for some reason gravy for turkey is more expensive then gravy for chicken what would I do in this scenario? Thanks for your recommendation on normalization.

Comment: In that case your design is properly normalized, since the price is dependent on both columns.

Comment: But if that's an uncommon exception, you could treat it as two different add-ons, e.g. `chicken gravy` and `turkey gravy`.

Comment: In a relational database you really want to steer towards relating things using a numerical foreign key that's issued once and once only. Using names like `gravy` as a foreign key is highly problematic as something as simple as changing capitalization can cause a mis-match and wreck your relationships. If what's called "A" today ends up being renamed to "Q" and later a new item "A" shows up, if you haven't properly adjusted your external references then this new "A" item will suddenly "inherit" a lot of dirty data.

Comment: @tadman On the other hand a value is a value and for learning how the operators & design & decomposition works enums/strings are clearer.

Comment: @philipxy Not really. It just promotes bad habits that need to be stomped out before they become ingrained. Use numerical "id" fields whenever possible. In exceptional cases use a UUID. This is database design straight out of the 1980s and we stopped doing it this way because it creates huge problems that aren't worth the really trivial conveniences it offers. If those were fixed SKUs you may have an argument, but they're not, they're textual labels that are entirely subjective. One person's "gravy" is another's "au jus".